# Why I can not add datas into lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
with open("lineup.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    ts = list()
    fb = list()

    for line in file:
        line = line[:-1]
        data = line.split(",")
        if (data[1] == "Fenerbahçe"):
            fb.append(line + "\n")
        elif (data[1] == "Trabzonspor"):
            ts.append(line + "\n")

    with open("ts.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file1:
        for i in ts:
            file1.write(i)

    with open("fb.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file2:
        for i in fb:
            file2.write(i)
print(fb)
print(ts)
```

And here is some datas from lineup.txt file

```
U. Çakır, Trabozonspor
Marc Bartra, Trabzonspor
İ. Kahveci, Fenerbahçe
S. Aziz, Fenerbahçe
Trezeguet, Trabzonspor
A. Bayındır, Fenerbahçe
Gustavo Henrique, Fenerbahçe
```

I am taking ∅ in both lists so I can not write datas into txt. I can't figure it out why

Comment: both conditions `if ... elif` get false

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean? I can not understand

Comment: `data[1] == "Fenerbahçe"` for example is never true. Double-check your data. `print(data)` should shed some light.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with your `split` function. If you split on comma, your second word of your list will start with a space. And if that is not your only word after the comma and space, you won't be able to match the equality anyways.

One way to solve this, is by using the "*in*" operator, avoiding the "*split*" completely.

```
for line in file:
    if ("Fenerbahçe" in line):
        fb.append(line[:-1] + "\n")
    elif ("Trabzonspor" in line):
        ts.append(line[:-1] + "\n")
```

If the matching is more complex than that, you may consider using regex and exploit word boundaries before and after your matching city names.